# What is .net alternative to jhipster

Tags: .net, jhipster

Which framework provides similar features to .Net as jhipster does for Java. I understand that there are separate libraries that can be brought together to work as the solution, but is there something pre-packaged to make things as quick and smooth as jhipster does?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is JHipster.NET Blueprint available that is meant to be used in a JHipster application.

For further details regarding basic setup, installation and application creation, please refer [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-dotnetcore).

And [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-net-sample-app-template) you can find the JHipster .Net Sample Application Template.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can use scaffolding to achieve a similar effect to jHipster, the technique is called scaffolding. 
You can do it with Visual Studio on Windows using .NET Framework - you create a MVC/Web API app that will create Controllers and Views based on your Model class, check this link [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/using-scaffolding-to-create-mvc-applications-with-visual-studio/).

You can also use .NET Core on Mac and Linux together with Yeoman to achieve the same thing, more info [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/yeoman.html).

Comment: Well, that would be wishful thinking at best. Scaffolding helps create an Empty app (yes, with login boilerplate) but it lacks in multiple ways: 1) no way to dictate "all" entities/relationships, and related UI behavior there of (filters, autocompletes), 2) no way to store the "script" config file in user-friendly format for regenerating the app when needed, 3) the app skeleton generated is Always monolithic, 4) no consideration is given to distributed caching, database configuration (beyond standard MS-SQL),to testing, and in .NET Core up to v.2 no sample meaningful config file is provided...

Answer (score 1):

ABP(AspNet Boilerplate) might be the candidate in .NET world.

It's not only a simple scaffolding tool, it also contains best practices and most popular open source packages combined together. And of course, you have choices between counterparts components.

The project can be found here:
[ASP Boilerplate project](https://aspnetboilerplate.com)

Answer (score 1):

To speed up development, you need a good technical framework and a code generator.

Regarding the framework you have the choice. Concerning the code generation, you can use a tool like [Telosys](https://www.telosys.org/) with templates for .Net adapted to what you want to generate with the framework you have chosen. FYI, this code generator is free, Open Source, lightweight and non-intrusive. It has no impact on the generated code and you can stop using it at any time.

See also this question : [Is there any freeware tool available which is like Codesmith?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035599/is-there-any-freeware-tool-available-which-is-like-codesmith)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Buul Smart Coding Platform but I don't know if .NET is available.